# Running virtualbox vm inside openstack vm

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, openstack

I'm trying to run virtualbox vm (virtualbox 6.1.4, vm iso image is ubuntu 16.04) inside openstack instance for some tests ( openstack is ocata, and instance image is ubuntu 14.04),  when i start vm in virtualbox, it fails. But I have started vm in virtualbox successfully on another openstack platform, what's different between these two platforms is physical server(the fail one using xeon silver 4210, the success one is xeon e5-2630), so is it due to cpu ? 
I checked the status of the nested boolean flag in the compute node and openstack instance, both display Y.

```
#  cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested
Y
```

The part of  virtualbox log info is below:

```
00:00:03.364654 emR3Debug: rc=VERR_VMX_UNEXPECTED_INTERRUPTION_EXIT_TYPE
00:00:03.855791 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 800x600
00:00:03.858580 ERROR [COM]: aRC=NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057) aIID={4680b2de-8690-11e9-b83d-5719e53cf1de} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={Argument aWidth is invalid (must be aWidth != 0 && aWidth <= 32767)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:06.822019 GUI: User request to power VM off on Guru Meditation.
00:00:06.822649 GUI: Passing request to power VM off from machine-logic to UI session.
00:00:06.822654 GUI: Powering VM down on UI session power off request...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the only difference between the two environments is the CPU used, then yes, pretty much by definition, the problem is due to CPU.

Comment: @womble  As all the hardwares will be upgraded to new cpu，we must find a solution. I will try changing all three levels os to ubuntu 18.04